# How can I fetch data from a dynamic page in Nextjs?

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to create some dynamic pages with basic functionality, which is fetching some data from external APIs. But when I try to fetch from a dynamic page I get the error:

```
TypeError: users.map is not a function
  4 |   return (
  5 |     <div>
> 6 |       {users.map((user) => {
    |             ^
  7 |         return (
  8 |           <ul className="row-active" key={user.id}>
  9 |             <li>{user.name}</li>
```

My code so far:

```
export default function Users({ users }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {users.map((user) => {
        return (
          <ul className="row-active" key={user.id}>
            <li>{user.name}</li>
            <li>{user.id}</li>
            <li>{user.username}</li>
            <li>{user.email}</li>
            <li>
              {user.address.street}, {user.address.suite}, {user.address.city},{" "}
              {user.address.zipcode}, geo: ({user.address.geo.lat},{" "}
              {user.address.geo.lng})
            </li>
            <li>{user.phone}</li>
            <li>{user.website}</li>
            <li>{user.company.name}</li>
          </ul>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const users = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/`).then(
    (res) => res.json()
  );
  return {
    props: {
      users,
    },
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const json = await res.json();

  return {
    paths: json.map((user) => {
      const userId = user.id;
      return { params: { userId: user.id.toString() } };
    }),
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

What triggers the error:

```
  const users = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${params.userId}`).then((res) => res.json());
```

Is there anything I'm missing? I saw some examples where this would work. My dynamic page is called *[userId].js*

I'm really stuck, thank you in advance!

Comment: do you log the `users` to check it is an array of objects?

Comment: @Ramineghbalian I think so, yes. I already succeeded in fetching every user, I'm just having problems in displaying them in a dynamic route

Comment: I copy your code, and its works, for example this URL works for me : `http://localhost:3000/users/7`